# php woocomerce cart divide and multiply

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, calculation

I have a complex way to calculate cart subtotal. however it seems that if i calculate the subtotal then tax / shipping and totals are not calculated properly. I was not able to figure out a solution so I took a different route.
i am now calculating the subtotals and then divide it by the number of items in the cart.
for example if my subtotal is: 39.4 and total number of items in the cart are 7
then i will do 39.4/7 = 5.62857142857
then in a separate loop ill make each item worth this price so that the subtotal will be equal to 39.4 in this example.

however i see 39.41 instead of 39.4

this in the calculator works fine as i end up with 39.4 however in php/woocommerce its giving me 39.41

Any idea what I could be doing wrong? I didn't post the code as I think its some rounding issue rather than the code it self.

Please let me know if I need to add any more info

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use a different logic to fix this issue.